# How to Sort array of object by this order?

Tags: javascript, sorting

Input:

```
var arr = [{ fName: "a" }, { fName: 1 }, { fName: "A" }];
```

Expected Output

```
var arr = [{ fName: 1 }, { fName: "A" },{ fName: "a" }];
```

supposed key fName is a employee name and we want to sort this object `[1,'A','a']` like this but in object form.
how to do this?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give precedence to numbers over strings checking the `typeof` variable, and returning `-1` or `1` accordingly:

| compareFn(a, b) return value | sort order |
| --- | --- |
| > 0 | sort a after b |
| < 0 | sort a before b |
| === 0 | keep original order of a and b |

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```js
const arr = [{ fName: "a" }, { fName: 3 }, { fName: "A" }, { fName: 1 }];

console.log(
  arr.sort((a, b) => {
    if (typeof a.fName === 'number' && typeof b.fName !== 'number') {
      return -1
    }
    if (typeof a.fName !== 'number' && typeof b.fName === 'number') {
      return 1
    }
    if (a.fName < b.fName) {
      return -1
    }
    if (a.fName > b.fName) {
      return 1
    }
    if (b.fName === a.fName) {
      return 0
    }
  })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to come up with a proper sorting function.

1. It should compare numbers with strings
2. It should make upper case first.

```js
const sortByFName = (a, b) => a.fName
  .toString()
  .localeCompare(
    b.fName.toString(), 'en', {
      caseFirst: 'upper'
    }
  )

const result = [{
  fName: "a"
}, {
  fName: 1
}, {
  fName: "A"
}].sort(sortByFName)

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort an array using any comparison code you want.

For example:

```
objArray.sort((a, b) => {
    // Some code for comparison
});
```

Learn more about the sort function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: I interpret the question as asking what to put in the "code for comparison" to produce the desired order.